# Icons in start menu are gone

Tags: windows-7, icons

My system is Windows 7 64bit. I start my PC today, and noticed that most of the icons of the applications in the start menu are gone...but the applications are still working. How can I get the icons back?

Comment: did you log on with your usual user account?

Comment: of course, i have only one account on that pc

Comment: Your profile may be corrupted. Are there any other strange symptoms?

Comment: @Scandalist, besides the missing icons, I have not found any other strange symptoms yet. All the applications, with/without the correct icon, works like a charm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out...there's no fix for this kind of issue. What I did was...I deleted the original installation files that **installer** copied to my computer. I think these installation are useless. I have a copy of them and stored in somewhere safe. Why I need another copy on my computer? But Microsoft does not agree :( They make a copy of the installation file on your computer, and pointing some resources to these copies.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your taskbar and select Properties.  In the Windows that appears select the Start Menu Tab.  Select Customize, and when you select Customize another smaller window appears, on the bottom left select Use default settings.  This will bring back all the default Icons you had.  Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks @Dude, tried already, but does not help me :(